# How to access props in stateless component that were mapped in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am wondering how can I access the props that were not passed, but mapped in mapStateToProps function to props in stateless component. So, for example if I map a value from the state to prop like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  test: formValueSelector('InfoPanel')(state, 'test'),
});
```

And if I expect some props from parent component like this:

```
export const InfoPanelForm = ({ readOnly, hasActionPoints}) => (
  <div>
    <Row>
      <Column>
        <VerticalSpacer space={4} />
        <Element>Info</Element>
      </Column>
    </Row>
  </div>
```

How can I access this property test now in this component?

Comment: `mapStateToProps ` will only passed map props.Thats the way to pass params and function to component either class or stateless

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN yes, but I asked how can I access this prop now, test in my case?

Comment: @Leff please check the below answer ad please add comment in case any issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access same as you done with `readOnly`.

Assuming you have `connect` call with given component `InfoPanelForm` and `mapStateToProps`

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(InfoPanelForm); //react-redux connect call
```

**component :**

```
export const InfoPanelForm = ({ readOnly, hasActionPoints, test}) => (
  <div>
    //..
  </div>
```